# Determining whether an input is a number in Python

Tags: python

I've created a code that requires the user to enter a number. The following code only allows the user to enter a number.

```
while True:
    strainx =input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")

    try:
        num_format=float(strainx)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Entry")

strainx=float(strainx)
```

This is only part of the code. I have several inputs which have exactly the same code, but with different names. One of these is to input a value for 'v'.

The last line 'strainx=float(strainx)' doesn't make sense to me as it is formatting strainx to be a float, however the input should only accept floats anyway.

Further on in the code there is an equation which involves v**2

If I get rid of the 'strainx=float(strainx)' line and the same line for all of the other inputs (including v) the equation involving v**2 no longer works and gives me the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Can anyone help explain to me why this is? Surely I should be able to get rid of the 'strainx=float(strainx)' lines without there being an error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in your `try` block, you assign to a new variable. If you assign back to `strainx`, you don't need to do anything more.

```
while True:
    strainx = input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")
    try:
        strainx = float(strainx)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Entry")
```

> The last line 'strainx=float(strainx)' doesn't make sense to me as it
>   is formatting strainx to be a float, however the input should only
>   accept floats anyway.

It is not formatting, but rather creating a float from the string. Objects in Python have defined types, which are how they are represented internally. If your variable is a string, you can't use it like a float, you have to tell Python explicitly you wish to make a float from it, which you do. When you do this, it returns a new float you need to use instead of the string. By assigning back to the same name, you can achieve the effect you want.

Alternatively, just use the new name from that point on.